# Problem with a SQLite raw query!

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to do a raw query in SQLite.

I want to select all from one table where id equals another column from another table, but can't get it to work properly.

The query I've been trying to do is in it's current state:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + table1 + " WHERE " +
            id + " EQUALS " + FriendsIntId + 
            " FROM " + table2
```

There is obviously something wrong here, can someone point it out to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `EQUALS` keyword does not exist in SQLite. Use `=` instead.
- Multiple `FROM` clauses have no meaning. Read the [SQLite SQL syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) documentation on selects. Maybe you want a subselect:

  ```
  SELECT * from table1
   WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM table2 )
  ```

  ?

Comment: Yeah that solved it, and thanks for the link have been searching for some documentation, although I never thought of searching only for SQLite docs, since I thought it was mostly the same. Pretty stupid of me. Anyway thanks again :)